# Method to get top index of flatlist in react native

Tags: react-native

Is there a provided method to enable us to get the index of the top item of the FlatList when we scroll it ?

Answer (score 26):

You can access the index of each row in this way:

```
   <FlatList data={this.state.dataList}
     ...
     renderItem={({item, index}) => this.renderRow(item, index)}
     ...
     console.log("current index is " + index)

   />
```

this will give you the index of the top row.

Comment: This answer is correct. I was able to get the index using this answer. Thanks alot!

Comment: Hey Thunder , I put the index but it is saying `Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.`Please help me out.

Comment: @MdForhadSarkar Make sure you're having index as a param in renderRow function

Comment: This code do not answer the question of this topic. renderItem is used to render each row. It do not get the top index of while scroll.

Answer (score 5):

there is no method to get it directly.

but you can compute it by scrollview offset, if you know the layout of every item.

implement onScroll on flatlist, like

```
<FlatList onScroll={(e)=>{
     let offset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
     let index = parseInt(offset / height);   // your cell height
     console.log("now index is " + index)
}}>
```

ps: don't forget to subtract the header layout if contains

Comment: Its a good idea but if my item height is dynamic how to get the height of the item

Answer (score 4):

Here is the right way to get index of items of flat list:

```
    <FlatList
        horizontal
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item: rowData,index }) => {
        return (
        <Card

            containerStyle={{flex:1,marginBottom:30,backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',}}>



            <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 ,fontSize:30}}>
                {'Comments:'}
            </Text>
            <Text  style={{width:290}}>
                {rowData.comment}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.text }>
                {'\nIndex:'+index}
            </Text>


        </Card>
        );
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to use the prop onViewableItemsChanged and get from the data returned by the callback the index of the first element displayed in the list. Remember to set also the prop viewabilityConfig so the component can determine where you consider an object displayed or not.

```
import React from "react";
import SwiperFlatList from "react-native-swiper-flatlist";

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component { 
// INSIDE A COMPONENT
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.currentIndex = 0;
    this._updateIndex = this._updateIndex.bind(this);
    this.viewabilityConfig = {
      itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50
    };
  }

  _updateIndex({ viewableItems }) {
  // getting the first element visible index
    this.currentIndex = viewableItems[0].index;
  }

  render() {
    return  // ...
      <SwiperFlatList
              loop={false}
              index={0}
              onViewableItemsChanged={this._updateIndex}
              viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}
            >
             {data}
            </SwiperFlatList>;
            }
}
```

instead of swiper-flat-list you can use the FlatList.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get an index of FlatList item - spread the itemData inside renderItem.

```
 <FlatList
       data={someData}
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
       renderItem={ ( {item, index} ) => // use {item, index} instead of itemData

        <MyComponent index={index} />    
  />
```

Comment: Can you explain more , Please !

Comment: @Forhad, just check the docs [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist}, It says: `renderItem` Takes an item from data and renders it into the list. Provides additional metadata like `index` if you need it

Answer (score 0):

View has an onLayout event which you could use to receive the x and y for the element. This is likely to require you to pass in a function in prop that will then receive the updates from each view in your flatlist. What are yo utrying to use it for?

Answer (score 0):

For those who want an easy way, `react-native-swiper-flatlist` provides `getCurrentIndex` and `OnIndexChange` methods to find index.