# Get row wise state inside flatlist in react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist and inside flatlist I Have a radioform. I have 2 items of radioform 'P' and 'A' Here is the picture of that [image]

Here I need to post the selected item.My Problem is if I select P then all row value is P when I post and if I select A all row value is A . I have a logic that I have to get the row id wise state get to post . Here so far I have  code

```
      export default class attendancetest extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
            super(props);
             this.state = {
             data: [],
             rollno:"",
             typeofattendance:1,

             animating: true
           };
        }
           componentWillMount() {
           this.fetchData();
           }
        fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await 
        fetch("http://192.168.1.208:8082/students/all");
            const json = await response.json();
            this.setState({ data: json });
               };
              closeActivityIndicator = () =>
             setTimeout(
         () =>
    this.setState({
      animating: false
    }),
  4000
);

           componentDidMount = () => this.closeActivityIndicator();
            render() {
           const animating = this.state.animating;
           return (
           <View
          style={--Style Code 
           }
          >
    <Logo />

    <Text style={styles.titleText1}>
      Test                           Section A Class 11th
    </Text>
    <ActivityIndicator
        --Some Code 
    />

    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>Roll & Name                          Present Or Absent</Text>
    </View>
    <FlatList

      data={this.state.data}
     // rollno={this.state.data.rollno}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      renderItem={({ item,index }) =>  (
        <View
          style=--Style Code 
        >
          <Text
            style=--style code
          >
            {item.rollno}
            --
            {item.name}
          </Text>

          <RadioForm
            animation={true}
            buttonColor={"#C2E3A9"}
            index={1}
            formHorizontal={true}
            labelHorizontal={true}
            buttonStyle={{ marginRight: 20 }}
            radioStyle={{ paddingRight: 20 }}
            //  labelHorizontal={false}
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              paddingRight: 20,
              flexDirection: "row",
              width: 30
            }}
            radio_props={radio_props}
            initial={this.state.typeofattendance}

           // initial={value => {
             // this.setState({ value: value });}}
            isSelected = {true}
           // radio_props

            onPress={value => { index=
              this.setState({ typeofattendance: value });
            }}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          />


        </View>

      )}
      // keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}

      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

    />
     <Button title="Submit" onPress={() => this.insert()} />
  </View>
);
                }


          insert = () => {
           var numstudent = this.state.data.length;
           var datatest=[]
           var data1;
           for(var i=0;i<numstudent;i++){
            data1={"rollno": this.state.data[i].rollno, "typeofattendence": 
            this.state.typeofattendance};
           datatest.push(data1);
             }
             console.log(datatest);
            }
            }
```

Here this portion I can get P to A but not in particular row

```
              </View>
            onPress={value => {
              this.setState({ typeofattendance: value });
              }}
```

How to get row wise state get inside flatlist .
Here in these portion I check the radiobutton check item in button click

```
    var numstudent = this.state.data.length;
    var datatest=[]
    var data1;
    for(var i=0;i<numstudent;i++){
       data1={"rollno": this.state.data[i].rollno, "typeofattendence": this.state.typeofattendance};
       datatest.push(data1);
      }
   //   console.log(datatest);
```

Comment: You are sharing the same state in every row in the flatlist `typeofattendance `. You have to change state index wise.

Comment: brother How can i do that ?? i got the issue .

Comment: Think I get it will check thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023541/ to get some ideas, basically you have to move your renderItem to another class so that you can keep individual states (just as it is depicted in that question) BUT your problem is even worse because you need to read those "individual typeofattendance" later (you need to send them right?). Your best shot is to use Redux or Redux-Saga or another central state manager. I tried to edit your code for you, but since you didn't provide your full code I was not successful. Please provide us with your full code.

Comment: @DNA.h I have Edited My code can you check it

Comment: @DNA.h I have provided my full code can you check it now